# A question about the function field of the cuspidal cubic

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand function fields of affine varieties. In the book I'm reading, a function field of a variety $V = V(I)$ was defined to be the set

$$
K_V = \left\{\frac{f}{g}, f,g\in \mathcal{O}(V) : g \notin I\right\}
$$

where $\frac{f_1}{f_2} \sim \frac{g_1}{g_2} \iff f_1 g_2 - f_2 g_1 \in I$.

Now to understand this better I'm trying to the following exercise:

[image]

First of all I'm struggling to understand of the domain of the function $\phi^*$, why is it the function field of $V$, $K_V$? The map $\phi$ has codomain $V$ right, but I don't quite what is $F$ here. Also to show that $\phi^*$ is a homomorphism I need to show that $\phi^*(FG) = \phi^*(F)\phi^*(G)$, but not really sure how to proceed here.

Comment: $F$ is an element of your function field, an element of $Frac(k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2))$, it is represented (non-uniquely) by a rational function in $x,y$ whose denominator is not in the ideal $(x^3-y^2)\subset k[x,y]$

Comment: Ok so the domain of $F$ is $V$ right? How does $F$ act on points in $V$?

Comment: $F$ is an element of $Frac(k[x,y]/(x^3-y^2))$. It is also a function $(V-(0,0))\to k\cup \infty$, where I removed $(0,0)$ the only singular point.

Answer (score 1):

An element $F$ of the function field $K_V$ is equivalent to a rational map $\hat{F}: V \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$. We can pre-compose this with $\phi$ to get a map
$$
\mathbb{A}^1 \overset{\phi}{\to} V \overset{\hat{F}}{\dashrightarrow} \mathbb{P}^1 \, .
$$
So we get a rational map (and in fact, a morphism) $\mathbb{A}^1 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1$, which as above, is the same thing as an element of the function field of $\mathbb{A}^1$, which is $k(t)$, the field of rational functions in one variable. Thus the morphism $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1 \to V$ induces a $k$-algebra homomorphism by pre-composition:
\begin{align*}
\phi^*: K_V &\to k(t)\\
F &\mapsto F \circ \phi
\end{align*}

In this way, we get a contravariant functor from the category of varieties over $k$ to the category of function fields over $k$.

For instance, in your example where $V: y^2 = x^3$ is the cuspidal cubic and $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1 \to V, t \mapsto (t^2, t^3)$, then
$$
\phi^*(f) = f(\phi(t)) = f(t^2,t^3)
$$
for all $f \in K_V$.